# Why does p4v open a new window for each diff?

Tags: windows-10, p4v, araxis-merge

On my previous Windows 7 based computer (which I can no longer refer back to because it died), I used the Perforce p4v client, and changed its preferences to use Araxis Merge as the diff application.  In that environment, if there was already an open Araxis Merge window, performing a diff in p4v would cause the diff result to appear in a new tab of the already open window.

In contrast, on my new Windows 10 based computer, I am using the latest version (191.183.0398) of p4v, but the same version of Araxis Merge.  In this new environment, performing a diff in p4v always opens a new Araxis Merge window, even though there is a already open Araxis Merge window.  That is *not* what I want.

Is there a way to configure p4v to use an already open window of the diff application, instead of always opening a new window?

### Diffs outside of p4v

The problem does not seem to be with my diff application, Araxis Merge.  As a test, I can perform a diff via the context menu in Windows Explorer.  If there is already an open Araxis Merge window, performing a diff in this way causes the diff result to appear in a new tab of that existing window.  That is what I want.

This test also seems to rule out the Windows 10 operating system as the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I configured p4v to execute Merge.exe as the diff application.  However, Araxis Merge has another executable named Compare.exe that I should use instead.  When I configure p4v to use Compare.exe, performing a diff in p4v opens a new tab in an already open window of Araxis Merge, as desired.

The following is an example snippet of the correct p4v configuration.  In the menubar, goto Edit > Preferences, then to the Diff section.

[image: p4v default diff application preferences]

It finally dawned on me what I was doing wrong while reading the Araxis Merge command line documentation ( https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/command-line.en ), which says in part:

> Using merge.exe to start file and folder comparisons is not recommended, unless you really do want a new instance of Merge for each comparison.

Comment: I just had to relearn this, and found my own question and answer again.  Yay for me!